# Keep video time on website language change

Tags: wordpress, video, time

I'm currently working over one wordpress website and it is on 5 languages. So I add video by src as every language has its own video file and by changing language the file changes.

The website is on WordPress 3.8.1 and I input videos by

```
<video width="560" height="340" controls><br /> 
    <source src="address/wp-content/uploads/folder//number_language.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/><br /> 
</video>
```

How to get the current session play time and set it on the new session after language change?

Comment: It's a very good question but needs more research on your part (see [ask]). I'd try to search for JS cookies and real-time update for them.

Comment: I'm truly sorry for not being much specific, but i was literalry already dizzed by different information...  
So the website is on WordPress 3.8.1 and I input videos by  

<video width="560" height="340" controls><br />
    <source src="address/wp-content/uploads/folder//number_language.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/><br />
    </video>

Comment: After some more research on the topic I found this article, but I still didn't had any time left to try something...  
  
I would be gratefull to know your opinion about it.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#media-controller-position

Comment: You'll have to use the listener `ontimeupdate` and go updating a cookie, and then read it on the next session and set the start time based on it (or start from zero if no cookie present). I never wrote something like this, but I'm pretty sure that *only researching* here at [so] we are able to build a solution. I wrote an [answer yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22388047/1287812) for which I had zero knowledge, but as you can see it was built **only** with bits that I found here. Good luck!